# Flutter Recipient: null Tried call (getTranslated method)

Tags: flutter

I have added a new page to my application. But I can't use the getTranslated method. I'm getting this error The 'getTranslate' method was called null. Recipient: null Tried call. how can i fix this problem?

I called the files needed for the getTranslate method in this image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share the code without using images